# Modelling phase noise for self-hetrodyne method

Tags: computational-physics, laser, software, noise

I am trying to model the phase noise $\phi(t)$ of laser used in self-hetrodyne method using python code. The noise is time-dependent.  The noise follows the condition that

$$<(\phi(t)-\phi(t-\tau))^2> = \vert\tau\vert / \tau_c,$$
where < > represents the mean value.  I know this noise model can be generated using some stochastic process, but I don't know, since I don't have much knowledge in this area.  I tried to simulate the code using Weiner process.  But the above value is linearly fitting, but the slope is not same as $1/\tau_{c}$.  Any clue how to do this, I will attach my code below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_phase_noise(num_steps, dt, tc):
# Compute the Wiener increments
   dW = np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.normal(0, 1, num_steps)

# Initialize phase noise process
   pn = np.zeros(num_steps)

# Generate scaled phase noise process
   for t in range(1, num_steps):
       pn[t] = pn[t-1] - np.sqrt(2 / tc) * pn[t-1] * dt + np.sqrt(2 / tc) * dW[t]

    return pn

# Parameters
t_max = 1.0          # Maximum time (s)
dt = 0.01           # Time step size (s)
tc = 0.1            # Coherence time of the laser (s)
fiber_delays = np.linspace(0, 2*t_max, 100)  # Fiber time delays (s)

# Generate phase noise process
num_steps = int(t_max / dt)
phase_noise = generate_phase_noise(num_steps, dt, tc)

# Calculate MSD values for various fiber time delays
msd_values = np.zeros(len(fiber_delays))
for i, tau in enumerate(fiber_delays):
    shifted_pn = np.roll(phase_noise, int(tau/dt))
    msd_values[i] = np.mean((phase_noise - shifted_pn)**2)

# Calculate the expected exponential decay
expected_decay = np.exp(-fiber_delays / tc)

# Plot the MSD values and the expected exponential decay
plt.plot(fiber_delays, msd_values, label='Simulated MSD')
plt.plot(fiber_delays, expected_decay, label='Expected Decay')
plt.xlabel('Fiber Delay (s)')
plt.ylabel('Mean Squared Difference')
plt.title('Mean Squared Difference vs. Fiber Delay')  
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

this gives the output.  Any idea where did i made the mistake, any help is appreciable

[image]

Comment: The code doesn't generate the figure that is shown in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to see if your code is correct since you didn't provide details on how the process defined in that way should fulfill the required correlation $\langle(\phi(t)-\phi(t-\tau))^2\rangle = \vert\tau\vert / \tau_c$. I will propose an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, show that in some limit we get the desired correlation and lastly discuss how to obtain samples of the process numerically.

**The process:**

Let the stochastic process be an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process:
$$ \dot{ \phi}(t)=a^{-1}\phi(t)+\tau_c^{-\frac{1}{2}}\xi(t).$$
with $\xi(t)$ a Gaussian noise with
$$\langle \xi(t)\rangle=0, \quad \quad \langle \xi(t)\xi(t')\rangle=\delta(t-t').$$
We also fix the initial condition to be
$$\phi(0)=0.$$

Since the equation is linear, we can integrate it (see [Van Kampen's book](http://vattay.web.elte.hu/lectures/Non-equilibrium%20Statistical%20Physics/VanKampen.pdf) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process#Formal_solution))
$$ \phi(t)=\tau_c^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^t e^{-\frac{t-s}{a}}\xi(s)ds,$$
and compute any moment,
$$\langle \phi(t)\phi(t+\tau) \rangle = \frac{1}{\tau_c}\int_0^t ds\int_0^{t+\tau}ds'e^{-\frac{2t+\tau-s-s'}{a}}\langle\xi(s')\xi(s)\rangle=\frac{a}{2\tau_c}\left(e^{-\frac{\tau}{a}}-e^{-\frac{t+\tau}{a}} \right).$$

Therefore, the time correlation reads:
$$\langle(\phi(t)-\phi(t-\tau))^2\rangle =\frac{a}{\tau_c}\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{a}}-\left(e^{-\frac{\tau}{a}}+e^{-\frac{t+\tau}{a}} \right) \right).$$

So, in general, the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process does not have the desired correlations. However, in the limit $t\gg a$ and $a\gg\tau$ we have:

$$\langle(\phi(t)-\phi(t-\tau))^2\rangle \approx \frac{\tau }{\tau_c}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{\tau^2}{a\tau_c}).$$

Which coincides with the desired correlation for any $a$ provided that it fulfills the desired limits.

**Numerical implementation**

As you do in your code, you can integrate the stochastic differential equation with an Euler-like algorithm:
$$ \phi_j\approx \phi(j\cdot dt), \quad \quad \phi_j=a^{-1}\phi_{j-1} dt+\left(\frac{dt}{\tau_c}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}G_j(0,1).$$
Where $\phi_0=0$ and $G_j(0,1)$ is a Gaussian random number with zero mean and unit variance.

This is similar to what you do, but there are some differences:

1. You have an extra $\sqrt{2}$ factor multiplying the Gaussian random number, which I think is not correct.
2. You can choose anything for the constant $a$, but it should be greater than the enquired values of $\tau$. If $\tau\approx 1$, then try $a>10$.
3. It is important to do the limit $t\to\infty$ limit in the simulations. To do so, wait for what is usually called a "thermalization time" $t>a$ before your first measure.

Comment: How did you arrive at the expression of time correlation from the previous step? The step up auto-correlation are clear to me, but I do not understand the next step you defined time correlation.  Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @FearlessVirgo, I added intermediate steps to the calculations (present in the references that I supported). Basically, you can solve the SDE and use it to compute any moment. The integrals are easy to do since the noise is delta-correlated and there are only exponentials.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answer.